How to put an SVG on a point with QGIS Server and GetPrint request?
I am looking to overlay an image file, specifically /data/PR-carre.svg, onto a generated map at specific coordinates x, y. This will create a visual marker or point of interest on the map for the user.
I am using QGIS Server on a docker, here is an exemple of request I send :
http://localhost:8080/qgis-server/?SERVICE=WMS
&LAYERS=MyLayers
&VERSION=1.3.0
&REQUEST=GetPrint
&FORMAT=pdf
&CRS=EPSG:2154
&TEMPLATE=Basic
&map0:HIGHLIGHT_GEOM=POINT(X1, Y1)
&map0:HIGHLIGHT_SYMBOL=<StyledLayerDescriptor>??How to put my svg??</StyledLayerDescriptor>
&map0:EXTENT=X1,Y1,X2,Y2

I am trying to figure out how to add my "point of interest" in this request.
